# star * in ptd = (double *) malloc(30 * sizeof(double))

Tags: c

I read such an example：

```
double * ptd;
ptd = (double *) malloc(30 * sizeof(double));
```

It explains that

> malloc() allocates memory but it doesn't assign a name to it. However, it does return the address of the first byte of that block.

Since malloc return the `the address of the first byte of that block`, I assume the correct way is assign the address to ptd directly without star(*).

```
ptd = malloc(30 * sizeof(double));
```

The extra * would dereference the address.

What's wrong with my assumption?

Comment: Which `*` are you referring to? Your statement is a bit unclear because it refers to "derefernce" but there is no deref in any of the `*` occurences shown. Both snippets of code will work. But arguably the second one is better as the `(double *)` cast is not needed. See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: * in (double *) ty, I got it.